# How can I define a function which is the sum of other functions?

Tags: function-construction

I have a function which is summation of another function over different i,j iterators.

```
U[r] = Sum[V[r, i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 6, 10}]
```

and `V[r, i, j]` function depends on the values of i and j (has different parameters depending on value of i & j)

```
If[2 <= i <= 5 &&  7 <= j <= 10, 
  Evaluate[vhh[i_,j_,r_] = -ehh (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ahh (ra[i, j, r] - rshh)]}^2)], 
  vhh = 0];
If[i == 1 &&  7 <= j <= 10, 
  Evaluate[vch[i_, j_, r_] = -ech (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)]}^2)], 
  vch = 0];
If[2 <= i <= 5 &&  j == 6, 
  Evaluate[vch[i_, j_, r_] = -ech (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)]}^2)], 
  vch = 0];
v[1, 6, r_] := -ecc (1 - {1 - Exp[-Acc (ra[1, 6, k, o] - rscc)]}^2);
```

And v[i,j,r] is sum of vch, vhh and vcc. so U[r] will be

```
U[r_]:=Sum[vhh[i_,j_,r_] + vch[i_,j_,r_]+ vcc[i_,j_,r_], {i,1,5},{j,6,10}]
```

(not defined Vhh or Vcc values are considered 0)
The above code isn't intended to work in *Mathematica*; it is just pseudo-code for sake of defining my problem.

I was thinking of defining three different functions, Vhh[r], Vch[r] and Vcc[r], and summing the three functions into the final function, `U`, but it doesn't work (see below error). Mathematica doesn't allow me to add 2 or more functions to a third one. Do you have any ideas how to define `U` function in *Mathematica*?

```
U[r_] := Vhh[r] + Vch[r] + Vcc[r]
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag C in U[r_] is Protected.

Comment: Since you don't describe the failure mode when your say " ... but it doesn't work", it's hard to diagnose you problem, but here is a piece of general advice: use `U[r_] := Vhh[r] + Vch[r] + Vcc[r]`. Note the `:=` in place of `=`, it makes an important difference. And use `:=` when you define `Vhh`, `Vch` and `Vcc`, as well.

Comment: Sometimes you can get the `Tag...Protected` error when you define a symbol in multiple ways in the same session and they happen to be incompatible. If this is the case, simply `Clear[U]` before evaluating the one you really want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mathematica can not Sum functions

simply

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A[x_] := X + 1;
B[y_] := y + 3;
C[r_] := A[r] + B[r]
```

Will give you error of

> SetDelayed::write: Tag C in C[r_] is Protected. >>

Try making the function out summations directly, your function should look like

```
U[r_] := Sum[-ehh (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ahh (ra[i, j, r] - rshh)])^2), {i, 2,
      5}, {j, 7, 10}] + 
   Sum[-ech (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)])^2), {i, 1, 
     1}, {j, 7, 10}] + 
   Sum[-ech (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)])^2), {i, 2, 
     5}, {j, 6, 6}] + 
   ecc (1 - (1 - Exp[-Acc (ra[1, 6, r] - rscc)])^2);
```

And avoid { in definition of your function.

Comment: The error here is because `C` is a protected symbol. Try using lowercase `c` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You did not provide a definition of `v` or `ra` which would be helpful, but I suspect this may at least help you move in the right direction:

```
vhh[i_, j_, r_] /; 2 <= i <= 5 && 7 <= j <= 10 :=
 -ehh (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ahh (ra[i, j, r] - rshh)]}^2)
vhh[__] := 0

vch[i_, j_, r_] /; i == 1 && 7 <= j <= 10 :=
 -ech (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)]}^2)
vch[__] := 0

vcr[i_, j_, r_] /; 2 <= i <= 5 && j == 6 :=
 -ech (1 - {1 - Exp[-Ach (ra[i, j, r] - rsch)]}^2)
vcr[__] := 0
```

These functions are defined for three parameters, while your apparent uses in `U[r_] = Vhh[r] + Vch[r] + Vcc[r]` has only one, therefore I do not know how to proceed.